# Calculate and display total as range slider moves

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate and display the result of three ranger sliders. The equation I'm trying to display is:

KM driven per year * Avg KM/100L / Price of fuel

I've gotten the sliders to display each of their individual values but I'm not sure how to display the calculation.

[View Codepen](https://codepen.io/verygoodcreativeco/pen/VwvBqRQ)

```
<div>
  <p>KM Driven per Year</p>
  <p id="myAvgKM"></p>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="300000" value="80000" step="1000" class="slider" id="kmdriven">

  <p>On average, my truck gets around:</p>
    <div class="response-container">
      <p id="myAvgKPL"></p>
      <p>L/100KM</p>
    </div>
  <input type="range" min="4" max="60" value="40" id="avgkm">

  <p>Diesel prices are usually:</p>
  <p id="price"></p>
  <input type="range" min="0.000" max="3.000" value="1.308" step=".001" id="priceValue">
</div>

<div>
  <p>In the first year alone, our services would save you:</p>
  <p id="savings"></p>
</div>

function calculate () {
// Display KM Driven Slider
var kmPerYear = document.getElementById("kmdriven")
var kmOutput = document.getElementById("myAvgKM")
kmOutput.innerHTML = kmPerYear.value;

kmPerYear.oninput = function() {
  kmOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
}

// Display Avg Mileage
var avgKM = document.getElementById("avgkm")
var avgKMOutput = document.getElementById("myAvgKPL")
avgKMOutput.innerHTML = avgKM.value;

avgKM.oninput = function() {
  avgKMOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
}

//Display Avg Price
var avgPrice = document.getElementById("priceValue")
var priceOutput = document.getElementById("price")
priceOutput.innerHTML = avgPrice.value;

avgPrice.oninput = function () {
  priceOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
}

// The Math!


  document.getElementById("savings").innerHTML = "$ ";

}
```

Comment: is it okay with you to use jQuery in place of pure JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need map your function to `onchange` event as

```
<input onchange="calculate()" type="range" min="0" max="300000" value="80000" step="1000" class="slider" id="kmdriven">
```

Remove oninput, because your slider don't handle `oninput` change to `onchange`

Add formula for total saving

```
var total = (kmPerYear.value / 100) * (avgKM.value * 1.2) * avgPrice.value;

document.getElementById("savings").innerHTML = `$ ${total}`;
```

```js
function calculate () {
// Display KM Driven Slider
var kmPerYear = document.getElementById("kmdriven");
var kmOutput = document.getElementById("myAvgKM")
kmOutput.innerHTML = kmPerYear.value;

// Display Avg Mileage
var avgKM = document.getElementById("avgkm")
var avgKMOutput = document.getElementById("myAvgKPL")
avgKMOutput.innerHTML = avgKM.value;


//Display Avg Price
var avgPrice = document.getElementById("priceValue")
var priceOutput = document.getElementById("price")
priceOutput.innerHTML = avgPrice.value;

// The Math!
var total = (kmPerYear.value / 100) * (avgKM.value * 1.2) * avgPrice.value;
  
  document.getElementById("savings").innerHTML = `$ ${total}`;
  
}
```

```css
.response-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>KM Driven per Year</p>
  <p id="myAvgKM"></p>
  <input onchange="calculate()" type="range" min="0" max="300000" value="80000" step="1000" class="slider" id="kmdriven">
  
  <p>On average, my truck gets around:</p>
    <div class="response-container">
      <p id="myAvgKPL"></p>
      <p>L/100KM</p>
    </div>
  <input  onchange="calculate()"  type="range" min="4" max="60" value="40" id="avgkm">
  
  <p>Diesel prices are usually:</p>
  <p id="price"></p>
  <input  onchange="calculate()"  type="range" min="0.000" max="3.000" value="1.308" step=".001" id="priceValue">
</div>

<div>
  <p>In the first year alone, our services would save you:</p>
  <p id="savings"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Displaying the total was the issue and that snippet did the trick. I'm curious, what is the meaning of the syntax `$ ${total}`? What do the backquotes signify and what is the purpose of the curly brackets?

Comment: it is interpolation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals, if answer help you, you can mark as accepted thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the window onload script at end of your javascript file
`window.onload=calculate;`

https://codepen.io/sanjayism/pen/vYNaoap

Comment: This piece was necessary to get the code to run on page load, which I definitely wanted. Additionally, I added window.oninput = calculate; in order to update the total value as the sliders were adjusted. Thanks for your help!